# Electron dev tools don't show

Tags: javascript, electron, sequelize.js, google-chrome-devtools

Whenever I start my Electron app & tell it to open the dev tools, nothing happens.  Manual selection from the menu doesn't do anything, nor does [Ctrl] + [Shift] + I.  All the other posts I've seen say to call `openDevTools()` or use the keyboard shortcut - both of which I'm doing to no avail.

Here is my window initialization code:

```js
const Window = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1200,
    height: 800,
    webPreferences: {
        preload: path.join(__dirname, "..", "preload.js"),
    },
});
Window.webContents.openDevTools();
Window.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, "../..", "index.html"));
```

I'm using Electron 20.01 on Windows 10.

**Edit** Further up in my file I'm connecting to an sqlite3 database using Sequelize.  It would appear that *that* code is somehow preventing the dev tools from opening.

This code:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
    dialect: "sqlite",
    storage: path.join(__dirname, "..", "..", "db.db"),
});
```

Is the culprit.  Commenting it out results in the dev tools showing.

Comment: hm. Can you move the opendevtools call after `loadFile` and `await` loadFile?

Comment: @pushkin That did it!  I guess it makes sense in hindsight - the window doesn't _really_ exist until it's loaded a file.  Make that an answer and I'll accept.  Thanks.

Comment: I tried this using Electron 13.0.1 and the dev tools window still does not open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the `webContents` of the window is only initialized once you navigate the window to a page, so you should open the devtools only after you've done that, preferably after awaiting the load.

```
await Window.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, "../..", "index.html"));
Window.webContents.openDevTools();
```

Comment: Thank you. I got mad with this problem for weeks and this solves it.

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem in my case.

Comment: @geometer Is the `devTools` property enabled on your window (should be the default so make sure you're not disabling it somewhere)

Comment: @pushkin Yes, absolutely all demands been fulfilled. No effect. The only solution is:
```const openDevTools = (mainWindow) => {
    const devtools = new BrowserWindow()
  mainWindow.webContents.setDevToolsWebContents(devtools.webContents)
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools({ mode: 'detach' })
}
```